# Can I auto restart tomcat jvm on out of memory exception

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm

I know that this is not "best practice" but I would like to know if I can auto restart tomcat if my deployed app throws an outofmemory exception

Comment: The proper answer is that the Java authors should never have made OutOfMemoryErrors catchable. They should always kill the VM, and a script or manager would handle the restart. Furthermore, Tomcat shouldn't be catching these either.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can try to use the OnOutOfMemoryError JVM option

```
-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="/yourscripts/tomcat-restart"
```

It is also possible to generate the heap dump for later analysis:

```
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

Be careful with combining these two options. If you force killing the process in "tomcat-restart" the heap dump might not be complete.

Comment: I actually get a permgen error due to a classloader leak I guess. Will the same flag work in that scenario also?

Comment: But what is the content of "tomcat-restart"? Is it just shutdown.bat, startup.bat?

Comment: You need to kill it using signal 9 (kill -9 PID) because it's not in a useful state. Unfortunately it can't be used for safe Tomcat process recycling.

Comment: @Dan In which file should I add these lines?

Comment: @Dan Where should I ad these lines to achieve the restart?

Comment: @OddDev These are JVM options. If you use startup.bat/startup.sh that ship with Tomcat try adding them to JAVA_OPTS environment variable. On Windows, create setenv.bat in tomcat/bin and insert "set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError  ...".

Comment: @Dan Thanks! Going to try this. :)

Comment: FWIW, I put together a tomcat restart script, to be hosted in tomcat bin directory. There is a catch - JVM doesn't close descriptors after forking, so you need to close them, or restarting will cause binding errors : https://pastebin.com/T1HYqV4S Linux specific and so on, use OYOR.

Comment: Can i assume that the 1st command will b executed only when the mem. dumping will be complete?

Answer (score 7):

I know this isn't what you asked, but have you tried looking through a heap dump to see where you may be leaking memory?

Some very useful tools for tracking down memory leaks:

```
jdk/bin/jmap -histo:live pid
```

This will give you a histogram of all live objects currently in the JVM.  Look for any odd object counts.  You'll have to know your application pretty well to be able to determine what object counts are odd.

```
jdk/bin/jmap -dump:live,file=heap.hprof pid
```

This will dump the entire heap of the JVM identified by pid.  You can then use the great [Eclipse Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) to inspect it and find out who is holding on to references of your objects.  Your two biggest friends in Eclipse Memory Analyzer are the histo gram and a `right click -> references -> exclude weak/soft references` to see what is referencing your object.

jconsole is of course another good tool.

Comment: Thanks for the hprof command, good to have it in the arsenal...:) I use visualvm for such things normally.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately when you kill the java process. Your script will keep a reference to the tomcat ports 8080 8005 8009 and you will not be able to start it again from the same script. The only way it works for me is:

-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p" and then another cron or monit or something similar to ensure you have the tomcat running again.

%p is actually the JVM pid , something the JVM provides for you.

Comment: There is a dedicated: `-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError`. No need to deal with `kill` command and magical `%p`.

Answer (score 5):

not easily, and definitely not through the JVM that just suffered the out of memory exception.  Your best bet would be some combination of tomcat status monitor coupled with cron scripts or related scheduled system administrator scripts;  something to check the status of the server and automatically stop and restart the service if it has failed.

Comment: Looks like this is the general consensus...:(

Answer (score 4):

Generally, no.  The VM is a bad state, and cannot be completely trusted.

Typically, one can use a configurable wrapper process that starts and stops the "real" server VM you want. An example I've worked with is "Java Service Wrapper" from Tanuki Software http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp

I know there are others.

To guard against OOMs in the first place, there are ways to instrument modern VMs via interface beans to query the status of the heap and other memory structures. These can be used to, say, warn in a log or an email if some app specific operations are pushing some established limits.

Comment: Tanuki's wrapper is definitively the best way to go

Comment: +1 in my case the script ran as part of the XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="/yourscripts/tomcat-restart was unable to bring the tomcat back up

Comment: Theres's also YAJSW  claiming to be fully compatible with JSW. You may want to give it a try if it suits your needs (it's open source), but from my experience JSW is worth the price.

Answer (score 2):

I use

```
-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='pkill java;/usr/local/tomcat/bin/start.sh'
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this? `` -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="exec \`ps --no-heading -p $$ -o cmd\`" ``