# Tomcat 7 doesn't start after it crashed

Tags: crash, overflow, heap-memory, tomcat7

My problem is, that I am running a webapp on Tomcat7 on a 2GB 2Core VPS and when the app crashes with heapoverflow exception Tomcat doesn't start or stop. When I try to access it via the browser it just hangs.

If I try to stop it looks like it stops but if I do it repeatedly it is supposed to throw an exception because it's already stopped, but this  is not the case. Only after 15 minutes am I able to start it up again.

I know that I should solve the heapoverflow problem, but the thing is I am simply not able as the framework I am using turned out to be nod thread safe and I have to create a new instance of a memory heavy object for every request :( I tried to come round the problem by adding some basic controller which only allows certain amount of objects to be created and the rest of the request are redirected to a Sorry-page. Since it is for a UNI project and the main goal is not being able to serve hundreds of users it's not important to make the framework thread safe.

Still I need to know why Tomcat does it after it crashes. Also it would help if you would have a better idea how to limit the number of these objects being in the memory at the same time.

++++++++++

At the moment the only solution I can see is to get say 2GB of more RAM so I will be able to serve some 15-20 users at a time.

Comment: SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-9008"]
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use <null>:9008

Comment: 25-Aug-2012 11:15:26 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService initInternal
SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[AJP/1.3-9008]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[AJP/1.3-9008]]

Comment: In the meantime it turned out it is the PermGen space running out of memory, there are suggestions to use VM-arguments to tackle the problem, but none of them really eleminated the need of periodically restarting Tomcat

Answer (score 0):

Generally after tomcat crashes with out of memory error it is in unusable state and the process has to be killed either manually or by using

```
catalina.sh stop -force
```

For a discussion on how to prevent those out of memory errors see
[Dealing with "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88235/dealing-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space-error)

Though ultimately you may need to throw more hardware at the problem.

This might also come handy:
[Can I auto restart tomcat jvm on out of memory exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405046/can-i-auto-restart-tomcat-jvm-on-out-of-memory-exception)